# When an object calls one of it's own functions, is it a case of closure where the object is passed in as the first variable to the method?

Tags: c#, .net, closures, clr

I think I understand how closure is implemented in C# and .NET. When the CLR detects that a function will be passed outside its scope and acts on a free variable, it will package the function and the variable into a custom class.

So how is this different from what happens when an `object` calls one of its own functions? The `object` itself is passed into the function as the first variable so that if the function needs any of the object's other functions, properties, or fields, it has access to them.

I think I'm missing something here, and would like some sort of explanation of what is going on in both cases: closure, and the case where an object is calling one of its own methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal method calls on an object has nothing to do with Closures; You only have a closure if you package that method call as a delegate!

In order to understand what's going on you need to have a good grasp on the concept of "value type" and "reference type". Talking about `Object` is not explicit enough in .net since `Object` is at the bottom of the hierarchy for everything, including value-types (`int` is also an `Object`). It's much easier to start thinking of method calls on pure reference types, like class instances.

Take your ordinary class variable and instantiation:

```
List x; // variable declaration
x = new List(); // instantiation
```

or, on a single line:

```
List x = new List();
```

The "body" of your instance will stay in a memory area that's called the Heap. The `x` that you're working with only holds a reference to that memory area, and that's why this is called a `reference type`.

When you call a method on the `List` using the `x` variable, the method needs to know on what list to work. So the method simply gets a reference to that body of the instance as the first parameter, the `this` parameter. It's incorrect to say the CLR or the Compiler passes "the object" because the object is always on the heap, it only passes a reference (or a pointer).

When the that method needs to call a different method of the same object, it simply passes the same `this` as the first parameter, the one it received itself.

A normal method call would look like this:

```
x.Add(Something); // calls instance method "Add" on "x"
```

When the compiler sees that it knows the reference to use `x` as the `this` (the first parameter, the hidden one) for the call to `Add`. There's no "closure" in there!

Here's what a closure would look like:

```
List<int> A = new List<int>();
List<int> B = new List<int>();

Action<int> aDelegate; // <-- declare a delegate type variable
                       //   Action<int> is a delegate that returns void and
                       //   takes a single int parameter.

aDelegate = A.Add; // <-- initialize the delegate using an instance method of object A
aDelegate(7); // <- notice the call! No reference to "A" because "A" is already stored in aDelegate

aDelegate = B.Add;
aDelegate(8); // <- notice the call! No reference to "B" because "B" is already stored in aDelegate
```

If you look closely at what happens when you call the delegate (`aDelegate(7)`), the compiler somehow needs to call the `Add` method on object `A`, but you can't see that, it's hidden. The delegate encapsulates both the reference to the object `A` and the address of the `Add` method and that's why it's called a `closure`. For contrast look at what happens when you do `aDelegate(8)`; This time method `Add` is called on object `B`, but there's no way to guess that because again, the reference to object `B` was buried inside the delegate (the closure).

Comment: Can I upvote this twice??? Quick question: Where you say "notice the call! The reference to "A" is hidden"...is it hidden? Or does the `Delegate` `aDelegate` already have a reference to `A`, and so `"A"` doesn't need to be passed into the call to `aDelegate`? Since `"A"` is already stored in `aDelegate`, when Invoke is called on `aDelegate` and it in turn calls `Add`, it just passes the reference to `A` into `Add` as the first parameter?

Comment: Whoops, hadn't read the whole thing yet...I see I just basically said the same thing you already had explained. :-)

Comment: So can you explain closed and open delegates to me? Or should I open a new QA for that?